# Devise gem skip confirmation and skip confirmation via email both at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems

I am using devise gem and while creating user I want to skip confimation! and skip confimation email for example:

```
User.create(:first_name => "vidur", :last_name => "punj").confirm!.skip_confirmation!
```

But it skips only confirmation and doesn't skip sending confirmation email. Can any one give me an idea to skip both.

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Confirmable#

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to call skip_confirmation! before you save the record.

Try

```
user = User.new(:first_name => "blah")
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save
```

Comment: This will skip sending confirmation email only but not confirm the user to log in via log in form.

Comment: According to the devise code.. skip_confirmation sets the confirmed_at attribute ... The same thing confirm! does. See: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L116

Answer (score 5):

You are calling User.create before skip_confirmation!, you need to call User.new and user.save later.

Try

```
  user = User.new(:first_name => "vidur", :last_name => "punj")
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save!
```

Comment: Great catch! Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

set the confirmed_at field

```
User.create!(confirmed_at: Time.now, email: 'test@example.com', ...)
```

useful in seeds.rb

```
User.create_with(name: "Mr T", company: "Comp X", password: 'rubyrubyruby', password_confirmation: 'rubyrubyruby', confirmed_at: Time.now).find_or_create_by!( email: 'test@example.com')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Got the solution:
 @user=User.new(:first_name => "vidur", :last_name => "punj")
 @user.skip_confirmation!
 @user.confirm!
 @user.save
```

Comment: It is `@user.confirm` (without `!`) as of June 2021. See [Rubydoc for Devise-Confirmable](https://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Confirmable).

Answer (score 4):

If you are confused where to write `skip_confirmation!` method in controller as you have not generated devise controllers yet then:

Write this in your **`User`** model

```
before_create :my_method

def my_method
 self.skip_confirmation!
end
```

Now simply use:

```
user = User.new(:first_name => "Gagan")
user.save
```

Comment: This really works! but this triggers every time save is called, which includes 'insert' and 'update' to database. How can I only apply it to 'insert', not 'update'?

Comment: @Yang    You can use the "before_create :my_method" callback instead of before_save.

Answer (score 4):

```
after_create :skip_confirmation_notification
```

- check source code [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/8c9cc8d355825e2b7ae0b4dcdedee518831e3338/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb)

If you want to skip_confirmation_notification on certain condition only, use a proc

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need confirmations at all, you can remove the `:confirmable` symbol in your model.

Comment: I can not do that because I need the confirmation procedure for rest of the website. But want to skip it only for a special case of creating users.