# devise overriding sessions controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to add a message when user tries to sign in and it's not confirmed, I want to display this message in notice section, basically devise needs to provide this message to us but I don't see any message in this cases. So I decided to add it manually from sessions controller here is my code:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])

    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)

    if user.confirmed_at.nil?
      flash[:notice] = "my message here"
    end
    yield resource if block_given?

    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

end
```

the problem is flash[:notice] is empty after action is executed, in console I have

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-18 15:07:21 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xC86tz4kZjcSMqXOL/+qpwlh5VlSbnsvLj93N5jb3NI=", "user"=>{"email"=>"pers.maki.5@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "landing_page_reports" 
  LandingPageReport Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "landing_page_reports".* FROM "landing_page_reports" ORDER BY "landing_page_reports"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'pers.maki.5@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'pers.maki.5@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  commit transaction
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 193ms
```

how can I display this message?

Answer (score 0):

More simple way to do what are asking about is to add before_filter :confirmation_notice in you application_controller and check whether current_user.confirmed? or not.

ex ::

```
before_filter :confirmation_notice

def confirmation_notice
  flash[:notice] = "my message here" unless current_user.confirmed?
end
```

Do not forget to configure your views to show this flash notice.

[This](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) to learn how to configure your views.

Comment: flash is still empty on page

Comment: Did you add the loop on flash in your view like the provided link ?

Comment: my flash objects is like that 
      #<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007f16543d3d78 @used=#<Set: {:alert}>, @closed=false, @flashes={:alert=>"You have to confirm your account before continuing."}, @now=nil>

Comment: This means that your are requiring confirmation which means nobody can sign_in without confirming the email. To allow sign_in without confirmation use .skip_confirmation! take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818280/devise-gem-skip-confirmation-and-skip-confirmation-via-email-both-at-once

Comment: override devise confirmation_required? method in your model.